# Parallelization Python loop

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, processing-efficiency, parallelism-amdahl

I'm a bit lost between **`joblib`**, **`multiprocessing`**, etc..

What's the most effective way to parallelize a for loop, based on your experience?

For example :

```
for i, p in enumerate(patches[ss_idx]):
            bar.update(i+1)
            h_features.append(calc_haralick(p))
```

```
def calc_haralick(roi):

    feature_vec = []

    texture_features = mt.features.haralick(roi)
    mean_ht = texture_features.mean(axis=0)

    [feature_vec.append(i) for i in mean_ht[0:9]]

    return np.array(feature_vec)
```

It gets i patches of images then extract features via haralick

And this is how I get patches

```
 h_neigh = 11 # haralick neighbourhood
 size = h_neigh
 shape = (img.shape[0] - size + 1, img.shape[1] - size + 1, size, size)
 strides = 2 * img.strides
 patches = stride_tricks.as_strided(img, shape=shape, strides=strides)
 patches = patches.reshape(-1, size, size)
```

Sorry if any information is superfluous

Comment: ***"...  the most effective way ...?"*** Well, that heck depends on what & how the loop-body actually does.

Comment: Hm, yes, I edited the post then

Comment: Is this all one one multi-core machine? That is, do you want to parallelize your process according to the number of cores on that machine? Or do you want to allow for distributed processing?

Comment: What is patches? Is it an array or list of simple elements, such as floats or integers? Or is its contents more complex/memory-large?

Comment: I have 16 cores available according to **multiprocessing.cpu_count()**

Comment: I wasn't asking about the number of cores. I asked how you wanted to do the parallelization. If you have 16 machines with 1 core each, than that's another possibility to parallelize. Do you want to allow for e.g. distributed processing.

Comment: This is one multi-core machine with 16 cores. So I suppose working on all cores in same time isn't a great idea

Comment: You can limit the number of cores, so that's not a problem.

Comment: What is `patches` *exactly*? "patches of images" is rather unspecific. Since I assume you send one image at a time over to `calc_haralick`, what is an image? What Python type? And if something like a (multi-)dimensional array, how large? The reason for this question is that you may want to do things differently depending on the size of the data.

Comment: I edited again the post, I didn't know it was size-dependant

Comment: It is not necessarily size dependent (or not principally); my suggestions, however, are. Note that your edits still don't mention the actual (average, median, range) size of the images. They could be 20 by 20, or 20K by 20K.

Answer (score 1):

Your images appear to be simple two-dimensional NumPy arrays, and `patches` a list or array of those. I assume `ss_idx` is an index array (i.e., not an integer), so that `patches[ss_idx]` remains something that can be iterated over (as in your example).

In that case, simply use `multiprocessing.Pool.map`:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

nproc = 10
with mp.Pool(nproc) as pool:
    h_features = pool.map(calc_haralick, patches[ss_idx])
```

See the first basic example in the [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

If you leave out `nproc` or set it to `None`, all available cores will be used.

---

The potential problem with multiprocessing is, that it will create `nproc` identical Python processes, and copy *all the relevant data* to those processes. If your images are large, this will cause considerable overhead.

In such a case, it may be worth to split your Python program in separate programs, where calculating the future of a single image is one independent program. That program would need to handle reading a single image and writing the features. You'd then wrap everything in e.g. a bash script that loops over all images, taking care to use only a certain amount of cores at the same (e.g., background processes, but `wait` every 10 images). The next step/program requires reading the independent feature files into a multi-dimensional array, but from there, you can continue your old program.

While this is more work, it may save some copying overhead (though it introduces extra I/O overhead, in particular writing the separate feature files).
It also has the optional advantage that this is fairly easy to run distributed, should the possibility ever occur.

---

Try multiprocessing, keeping an eye out on memory usage and CPU usage (if nothing happens for a long time, it may be copying overhead). Then, try another method.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for the time spent, one last thing, is this in the for loop or this is a completely different module ?

Comment: The `pool.map` call *replaces* the for loop.

Comment: Ok many thanks, I'll work on it and tell if I see any improvement (with %time as I don't get progressbar). I didn't know the ```pool.map``` _call_ had .append integrated. Thanks again !